# How do I fix my issue including google fonts?

Tags: javascript, fonts

My bad if the title makes the issue sound complicated, but the JavaScript code which I'm attempting to work with is generally simple, I just don't really know what I'm doing.

To specify what the issue I'm stuck with is then, my attempt at including a google font into the webpage just isn't working, following the examples that I have seen online it seems to be written fine, but something or other seems to be wrong regardless.

The font I am trying to use is: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redressed#standard-styles

And the code I tried writing to include it is: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Redressed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Also, I should have mentioned, I am trying to change the font of only one text type for the time being, specifically `h1`, in case that changes anything.

I'm fine with simply sharing the files though too if that'd help, since my main concern is just to get things sorted out and hopefully pass my class. Preferably while understanding what I'm doing, but admittedly I can't help feeling that the class itself is a more immediate problem.

Hopefully my inexperience isn't an issue, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link tag is correct, that should load the font-file inside your webpage, but you need an extra step, in your CSS add this on your `body` selector or any selector that need to use that font:

```css
font-family: 'Redressed', cursive;
```

Without this, it will not load your custom font.

PD: Don't worry about inexperience, everyone starts like that

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately, it still isn't working. Which is admittedly part of why I'm confused since everything I've looked at says that there shouldn't be issues.

Comment: Do you have it online to check?

Comment: Does this work? I'm admittedly unfamiliar with GitHub.

https://github.com/JamesA140/JSissue

Comment: Yeah, that works, you had a typo, I opened a pull request fixing it, you can check all the changes there https://github.com/JamesA140/JSissue/pull/1

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I admit that I'm impressed at how stupid my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Redressed&display=swap');
</style>

font-family: 'Redressed', cursive;
```

Comment: Could you point me somewhere that I could refresh myself on how to include this? If that sounds odd, I am wondering since I am trying to change only one of the text types' fonts, for the time being, and also since I don't remember using that method in the past so I may need to learn about it in the first place.
I admittedly I should have included mention of the single text type usage in the question, so I will edit it.